# dynamically get the image from different resource folder iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Currently I have the image folder the paths is Resource/images and inside the images folder there are several images, I would like to create dark mode using the same image name but the image are different in dark mode style and normal style. example(icon in dark mode is white but in normal mode is black)

I would like to know if I create 2 folder inside Resource/images/imageOneFolder and Resource/images/imageTwoFolder, how can I access the specific path to get the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to organize your icons in a better way for example:

- Resources/images/black/myicon_black.png
- Resources/images/white/myicon_white.png

Having this level of organization resolve the problem is very easy, I provide you two ways to resolve using the next logic:

```
@interface MyStructObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *imageName, *imageExtension, *fullImageName;
@end

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation MyViewController

// For this short version your icons needs to be white or black
// With the next code you can change the color of your icon
// Example: If dark mode active you need icons with whiteColor
// if not dark mode you need icons with blackColor

- (void)didExecuteShortVersion
{
    // Initial path document or bundle
    NSString *resourcesPath = @"Resources/images";
    
    // Getting objects from array or your own struct
    MyStructObject *myItem = [MyStructObject new];
    
    // The image full path
    NSString *fullImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", resourcesPath, myItem.fullImageName];
    
    // Image Object
    UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fullImagePath];

    // Image Container
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    [myImageView setImage: imageIcon];
    myImageView.image = [myImageView.image imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    
    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
        if (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleDark) {
            [myImageView setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
        else {
            [myImageView setTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
        }
    }
    else {
        // Dark mode is not available
        [myImageView setTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    
    // Adding view
    [self.view addSubview: myImageView];
}

#pragma mark - Life Cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Initial path document or bundle
    NSString *resourcesPath = @"Resources/images";

    // The image full path
    NSString *fullImagePath = nil;

    // Getting objects from array or your own struct
    MyStructObject *myItem = [MyStructObject new];

    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
        if (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleDark) {
            NSLog(@"Dark Mode Active");

            // Assuming your struct only has the first name of icon
            // Example: myItem.imageName -> myicon
            // Adding the last path of name to match icon _black -> myicon_black

            // If you have different kind of extension you can improve
            // the logic of this
            fullImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/black/%@_black.%@", resourcesPath, myItem.imageName, myItem.imageExtension];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"White Mode Active");

            fullImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/white/%@_white.%@", resourcesPath, myItem.imageName, myItem.imageExtension];
        }
    } else {
        // Dark mode is not available

        fullImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/default/%@_default.%@", resourcesPath, myItem.imageName, myItem.imageExtension];
    }

    if (fullImagePath != nil) {
        UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fullImagePath];

        // Change the CGRect
        UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        [myImageView setImage: imageIcon];

        // Add myImageView to the UIView
        [self.view addSubview: myImageView];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time.